# How do I import a large number of private keys into a wallet?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

I have a list of my private keys I generated, and I want to import all of them into SimpleWallet.

I have the Spend key, view key, address, and mnemonic from MoneroAddress' generations. I can format them differently if needed. I'd like to know how I can import many of these at once into SimpleWallet or any other wallet software.

Answer (score 4):

Most of the time associated importing keys will be the sync requirement before those keys can be used to sign a transaction.

I am not aware of any official script that can be used to important many keys at once. Even if such a script existed you would still need to sync each account before funds could be spent. simplewallet can only sync one account at a time. You could run multiple instances of simplewallet in order to speed up the sync process.

Answer (score 4):

You've have to restore them in separate instances of simplewallet. Typically, for simultaneous restores, you don't want to run more than 2-4 instances. Restoring is chunky, and can take a few hours!

If you wanted to script it you could do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

./simplewallet --wallet-file a.bin --password "somepassword" --restore-deterministic-wallet --electrum seed "all your words go here"
```

If you're running a current version from git, then you can leave out `--wallet-file`, as it will automatically set the wallet filename to be the wallet address.

Comment: did not know the bit about leaving out --wallet-file. by current version do you mean when pulling from head, or v0.9.4?

Comment: @bigreddmachine ah - by "current version from git" I meant git head, should've clarified:)